# Dubious Uniqueness

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to express a lack of uniqueness without requiring duplicity? That is to say, how can I describe a subject that may either be unique or a duplicate?

`normal` `common` `ordinary` etc. all contradict uniqueness by stating duplicity.

`non-unique` is the most apt term I can think of but even this seems to suggest repetition.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39617/discussion-on-question-by-peter-tomas-scott-dubious-uniqueness).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps simply use a generic noun that makes the question of the object's number salient (without specifying what that number is, since you merely demand n >= 1). *Item* would be such a term.

Other generic terms that emphasise number would be *exemplar* or *specimen*, with those two clearly implying n > 1 (but not that there exists a true duplicate; there might simply be multiple instances of the same class).

Comment: It could be related by DNA but not unique. (Paternal Twins)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest way would be to either not mention it at all, or to mention it as an aside:

```
A painting submitted to the gallery must be shipped in an appropriate box, and addressed directly to an assigned curator.
```

Or:

```
A (possibly unique) painting submitted to the gallery must be shipped in an appropriate box, and addressed directly to an assigned curator.
```

Answer (score 0):

English has many terms to place a subject's abundance on the unique-to-common spectrum. For example, ***rare*** and emphases thereon (***very rare***, ***extremely rare***) push the unique end of the spectrum. On another question @vickyace posted ***collectible*** as an answer in this vein as well. A subject so rare that there may be only one can be so stated, "may be unique," or "only copy known." Rare book catalogues will often state the number of known copies, and we are also used to it in art prints and limited editions.

Comment: A good answer but I found Benedict M.J.G's answer to be more suitable; he emphasised the ambiguity as opposed to expressing a *degree of uniqueness*. Thanks all the same.